# Nginx not redirecting to specific page

Tags: redirects, nginx

I want visitors to `domain1.example` to end up at a specific page on `domain3.example`. For testing, the DNS of `domain1.example` points at `domain2.example` and I have the following Nginx rule on `domain2.example` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain2.org.ssl.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name www.domain1.example domain1.example;
    return 301 https://www.domain3.example/en/specific-page;
}
```

This only takes visitors to `domain1.example` to `domain3.example` but not to the specific page.

I have also tried this which doesn't work either:

```
server {
    server_name www.domain1.example domain1.example;
    return 301 https://www.domain3.example/en/specific-page$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NEVER use a 301 redirect until you've got the configuration working as finalised using 302 redirects. The 301 is cached *indefinitely* by your browser.

You didn't say how you tested this. Using the Webdeveloper toolkit in your browser is better than just watching what happens on screen, but you really need should be checking using curl or similar from the command line (`curl -I https://www.domain1.example/`)

If your server is still returning an indirect redirect and you did restart it after changing the config, then there may be something elsewhere in the config - post the entire server{...} block, inlining any includes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have changed the response to `302` and then ran `service nginx reload`. Curl is still showing a 301 response for the naked domain:
`curl -I http://domain1.example
          HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`
but curiously nothing for the : `curl -I http://www.domain1.example                    
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.domain1.example`

What I posted in the original post is the whole server block. The rest of the config file includes lots of other detail but none of it refers to `domain1.org`. Are you suggesting I should post that anyway? Thanks again

Comment: You have something else going on then.  You have some other configuration that is doing the redirect.  Have you tested your DNS records are working the way you expect?